# Unable to update the record using API, getting 'An unexpected error'

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api

I am trying to update the record on ProfilePasswordPolicy using the following request and getting this error. Could not figure it out.

headers:

```
Content-Type:text/xml
charset:UTF-8
SOAPAction:login
Accept:text/xml
```

Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>token</sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ProfilePasswordPolicy">
                <fullName>KM_Authors_profilePasswordPolicy1642154314988</fullName>
                <maxLoginAttempts>10</maxLoginAttempts>
            </metadata>
        </updateMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But getting the following error in response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <updateMetadataResponse>
            <result>
                <errors>
                    <message>An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 668181172-550476 (-1717723389)</message>
                    <statusCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</statusCode>
                </errors>
                <fullName>KM_Authors_profilePasswordPolicy1642154314988</fullName>
                <success>false</success>
            </result>
        </updateMetadataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must pass all the values of the One ProfilePasswordPolicy object to make the changes.
Please refer following request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <SessionHeader>
            <sessionId></sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ProfilePasswordPolicy">
                <fullName>KM_Authors_profilePasswordPolicy1642154314988</fullName>
                <profile>km authors</profile>
                <obscure>true</obscure>
                <forgotPasswordRedirect>true</forgotPasswordRedirect>
                <lockoutInterval>15</lockoutInterval>
                <maxLoginAttempts>5</maxLoginAttempts>
                <minimumPasswordLength>10</minimumPasswordLength>
                <minimumPasswordLifetime>false</minimumPasswordLifetime>
                <passwordComplexity>3</passwordComplexity>
                <passwordExpiration>90</passwordExpiration>
                <passwordHistory>10</passwordHistory>
                <passwordQuestion>0</passwordQuestion>                
            </metadata>
        </updateMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```